# What is point of a temporary file name during a file upload?

Tags: php, file-upload, temporary-files

What is the point of `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`?

I know it is the name of the temporary copy of the file stored on the server but why do we need this when we have `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`?

I would assume it has to do with preventing name collisons, is that true? Are there other reasons? I'm using PHP syntax but I would guess the concept would apply to all the languages?

Comment: How does the system know where to write the file to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is not a PHP syntax.
2. `$_FILES['x']['name']` stores the name of the file on the user's filesystem - this is only extra information that is set up by the browser - just like `$_FILES['x']['type']`.
3. `$_FILES['x']['tmp_name']` stores the name of the uploaded file on the server.

#### EDIT:

When you upload a file, it is phisically stored on the server's hard drive. A name to the file (not the entire path) will be available in your PHP under `$_FILES['x']['tmp_name']` variable. You should move the file using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function. This function knows the path to the directory where the file is stored, so it's capable of moving the file to its new location.

`$_FILE['x']['name'] / ['type']` are actually completely useless as the're being set by the browser during file upload, therefore they could store false information.

Comment: I don't get point #1 and neither #2 nor #3 really answer the question any more than it states.

Comment: -@Crozin, so just the name is stored on the server or is it the file itself too? Where is this name kept on the server? I guess I'm confused on how the server decides when to store the name vs. the file itself?

Answer (score 1):

Because when someone uploads a file, until you save it somewhere, it's not really on disk under the 'name' until you explicitly save it somewhere else.  Until then it's contents are only found in the temporary file.

Comment: I like where this was going (so +1 to flush it out), although the content *can/is* very well be on disk (in a temp file) before saved to the final location .. I think, perhaps addressing: 1. what happens if the file upload is suddenly cancelled? 2. what happens to uploaded file data? Would give more insight into one reason for separation ..

Comment: thanks @Ray, I agree with -@pst, can you flush out your answer some more?